# How to redirect mysql output to file?

Tags: mysql, bash, mysql-workbench

When I run any select or update query in mysql workbench, it shows either

[image] or number of rows returned.

In my script, I use `mysql -u user -h ip db -se"select * from.."`

I have tried redirecting `mysql` output:

```
./script.sh >> script.log 2>&1
```

but it shows message only for error not when successfully run.

It does not show `27 row(s) returned`. So in that case, I could not check if any update statement, select or procedure run successfully.

How can I get output which runs successfully?

Comment: `2>&1` is telling bash to send the stderr on the same redirection as stdout.  No problem there.  Look at my answer, I tested and `-vv` adds what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution, in the options of `mysql`.

Run it like this:

```
mysql -u USER -h HOST -p PORT --password -vv -se "YOUR QUERY" >output.txt 2>errors.txt
```

The addition of the `-vv` parameter will give you the number of affected rows.
`-vvv` will also tell you how much time it took to run the query.

Ex: I ran this:

```
mysql -u Nic3500 -h localhost -P 3306 --password -vv -se "INSERT INTO stackoverflow.activity (activity_id, activity_name) VALUES ('10', 'testtest');" >output.txt 2>&1
```

And output.txt is:

> ```
> -------------- 
> INSERT INTO stackoverflow.activity (activity_id, activity_name) VALUES ('10', 'testtest')
> --------------
>
> Query OK, 1 row affected
>
> Bye
> ```

Comment: I think even when using a script (as in this specific question) _**you should not write the password directly in the mysql command**_. Much more so if you run this command from your terminal as the password will stay in your (bash) history.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a query using `INTO OUTFILE` like shown in the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html)

Example:
`SELECT DISTINCT name INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/out.txt' FROM people ORDER BY name ASC;`

Comment: I'm running from client system not on database server. So permission issue. That's why I'm using workbench to connect db. Query contains db server ip too.